# Is there a Microsoft hosted solution to test a Bing Maps Key?

Tags: maps, bing-maps, bing-api

Is there a Microsoft hosted/certified secure Bing Maps Key validator available online?
I need to

- check if the key works
- What the basic services activated in it are.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see if it works put the code in a simple code sample and see if the map loads. You can get a code sample of a simple page with a map at the bottom of this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427624.aspx

As for what is activated. All Bing Maps keys have access to the full Bing Maps platform. The only limitations are based on the type of key. If it is a Trial key it expires after 90 days. If it is a basic key it is limited to the free terms of use limits. Enterprise keys have few limitations. You can find out the type of the key by logging into your Bing Maps account at http://bingmapsportal.com and clicking on the Create or View Keys button.

Comment: It will load up if it has a valid key or not, but displays a banner across the map saying invalid credentials are specified.

Comment: Interesting. uBlock Origin on Firefox removes this banner, so I didn't notice it at first. If I test the map on Chrome or on Firefox, without plugin, the banner is indeed here. I'll remove my previous comment.